Join two table: get Invoice last row and join signing name (which has only one row)
Join two table:  get Invoice last row and join signing name (which has only one row)
Table Name: TAB1 Invoice



#
Product
Price




1
Laptop
22


2
Keypad
05


3
USB
08



Table Name: TAB2
signing authority name



#
sname




1
john cena



$array['data']=  DB::table('invoice')->last()
                ->join ('sname', 'sname.id', '=','sname.id');

$array['data']=  DB::table('invoice')
                ->join ('sname', 'sname.id', '=','sname.id')->last();

I tried both approach but I could not resolve the error.

Resolve what error?

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::last()

Please add the error message to the question by editing it. Please also indicate what the expected results should be.

My aim is to print last invoice record with signing person
          $array['data']=  DB::table('invoice')
          ->join ('sname', 'sname.id', '=','sname.id')->last();
          return view('invoice.iprint', $array);


You don't have a related key to base the join on. Also, Laravel's query builder has a first() function, it doesn't have a last(). Collections do have a last() function.

Please add the error message to the question by editing it. Please also indicate what the expected results should be. Don't just describe it with words, shiw the results as a tabular result.

Could you please share the error that you are facing?

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::last()

aynber is there any function/method  to get last row
